# PowerShell: Export Excel sheets as CSV

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I figured out how to export all sheets of a workbook as csv using powershell for excel 2007. The problem I have is that the script exports the same sheet 2x randomly. Sometimes it creates the 3 separate csv files like it should, and sometimes one of the csv files is a copy of another.
But it always prints:

```
A
B
C
```

Here is the code:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excel = new-object -ComObject "Excel.Application";
$excel.DisplayAlerts=$True;
$excel.Visible =$false;
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($scriptPath + "\file.xlsx");
foreach($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
    if($ws.name -eq "A" -or $ws.name -eq "B" -or $ws.name -eq "C") {
        Write-Host $ws.name;
        $ws.SaveAs($scriptPath + "\" + $ws.name + ".csv", [Object] Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSVMSDOS);
}
}
$wb.close($False)
$excel.Quit();
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel);
```

Running on Windows 7 x64, Excel 2007 SP2

Comment: I meant to say sheets.

Comment: AFAICS the code should work as you'd expect. Perhaps running Excel visible would give you some pointers as to what's going wrong.

Comment: It works if I perform a workbook close and open between each saveas. That's my workaround.